# User Defined Function to Add hours to a date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-function

I am trying to create a UDF to add 3 hours to date values using SSMS and I keep running into the following error when I call the function;

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

This is how I call the UDF:

```
SELECT TOP 5 dbo.to_eat('updated') FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
```

My query to create the function is as below;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[to_eat](@date_field NVARCHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(20) AS 
BEGIN
RETURN CASE
    WHEN @date_field <>'' AND @date_field IS NOT NULL AND @date_field <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -3, @date_field)
    -- WHEN @rating = 'AA' OR @rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'   THEN 2
    -- WHEN @rating = 'BBB' OR @rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]' THEN 3
    ELSE NULL
  END 
END
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why wouldn't you just use the built in [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function? .... and appropiate data types?

Comment: @Uueerdo, that function works, it is the one am calling inside the UDF but I need to format many date data points. The query becomes too long.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the single quotes around the column name, otherwise it is a litteral string, not a column name:

```
SELECT TOP 5 dbo.to_eat(updated) FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: yes, you are right... here a working fiddle sample https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ea8c31cdfe635ac6429538e00341272

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @Frederic.